# Group values keys based for each other value key

Tags: javascript

Sorry for bad title, I don't really know how to phrase this and this might be trivial problem ...

The data that comes from the array looks like this, each name can have an indefinite amount of `sequence`, what I want to do is group them by name and put each sequence in an array

```
[
{
    name: 'Mike',
    sequence: 'AAAA',
},
{
    name: 'Bob',
    sequence: 'ABAB',
},
{
    name: 'Bob',
    sequence: 'AAAB',
},
{
    name: 'Marvin',
    sequence: 'AAAA',
},
{
    name: 'Marvin',
    sequence: 'AABA',
},
{
    name: 'Marvin',
    sequence: 'BBBB',
},
]
```

What I am looking to return for each name by using `console.log(name, array)` for example would be something like this

```
Mike ["AAAA"]
Bob ["ABAB","AAAB"]
Marvin ["AAAA","AABA","BBBB"]
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: reduce and push

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal I have tried to use filter, map and Object.forEach but I am not quite sure how to use them together to get that result

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects) is your answer

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it seems you have tried some ways to solve the problem.

You can try following solution

- Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to convert your array into an object with `keys` as **name** and `value` as array of **sequences**
- In the `reduce` function, check whether the name exist in the resultant object. If it exists, **concat** the sequence to it (using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) else add a new entry with an array with sequence.

```js
let input = [{name:'Mike',sequence:'AAAA',},{name:'Bob',sequence:'ABAB',},{name:'Bob',sequence:'AAAB',},{name:'Marvin',sequence:'AAAA',},{name:'Marvin',sequence:'AABA',},{name:'Marvin',sequence:'BBBB',}];
let result = input.reduce((a, {name, sequence}) => Object.assign(a, {[name] : a[name] ? [...a[name], sequence]: [sequence]}), {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Excellent! I did not know about reduce, I do not understand the function yet but I know what to use it with next.

Answer (score -1):

```
inputArray.reduce((acc,{name,sequence}) => { 
                       let obj = acc.find(a => a.name === name); 
                       obj ? obj.sequence.push(sequence) 
                           : acc.push({name,sequence:[sequence]}); 
                       return acc;
                    }, [])
```